# How to query data from my ELM327 via BLE?

Tags: arduino-nano, esp32, bluetooth, ble

I have a HM-10 module connected to my Arduino Nano that I want to use to get data from a ELM327 OBDII.

I have been able to successfully connect to the ELM327 via:

```bash
AT

AT+RESET

AT+BAUD2

AT+ROLE1

AT+IMME1

AT+DISC?

AT+CON4823350035BB
```

I sent "`ATZ`" through my Serial Console and received nothing.

I then tried other baud rates, with no luck.

I suspected it needs to go to a specific characteristic.
So I found the names of the services and characteristics via Light Blue application.

But I see long hex values, where the `AT+CHAR` command from [the datasheet](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/uart/HM10/DSD%20TECH%20HM-10%20datasheet.pdf) gives a much shorter example.

I have been able to connect via an ESP32 using the `BLEDevice.h` library - ideally I would like to use a smaller microcontroller such as the Nano.

Is this possible with the Nano?